# startup ask failed for service MSSQLServerOLAPService

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I can't install SSAS (SQL Server analysis services) in multidimensional mode : I get an error at the end of the installation : startup ask failed for service MSSQLServerOLAPService. I was able at the first time to install SSAS in tabular mode, but I saw that a lot of tutorials use multidimensional cubes, so I wanted to change; I removed the existing SSAS service (via the SQL Server ISO installation disc), and install it but now in multidimensional mode, but I got this error.

I tried to delete the events in event viewer, with no success.

I read here and there this could be a permission problem, I mean the MSSQLServerOLAPService could have insufficient rights, but my level in windows and SQL Server users rights in very low. If I have some things to do, could you explain it simply?

I can access to SQL Server Management Studio, to the SQL Server installation media, to SQL Server Configuration Manager (so I can start/stop services). thank you.

The error is :

> Component error code:          0x80131600 Error description:
> Impossible to launch the service. Reason : « MSSQLServerOLAPService »
> service startup ask failed.

EDIT:
In the terrminal:

> # sc qsidtype MSSqlServerOlapService
>
> [SC] QueryServiceConfig2 réussite(s)
>
> SERVICE_NAME: MSSqlServerOlapService
>
> SERVICE_SID_TYPE:  UNRESTRICTED